# Multiple -ne filters powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PS script to automatically remove nearly all the group memberships from all the accounts in our Disabled User OU. I found a good script here that was modified by a contributor a few years ago to remove all groups with 1 exception.

I am now trying to find a way to add multiple exceptions.

We use AD groups to license our o365 mailboxes and we need to keep those group memberships intact for 90 days post separation.

The current script I have is this:

```
$ou = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Disabled,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter *
foreach ($user in $ou) {
$UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False} }
}
```

How would I modify this section to allow for more filtered groups?

```
if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!
Chris

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare against a list, instead of a string, you can use the `-notin` operator. For example:

```
$GroupsToKeep = 'Domain Users','O365 Licensing','Hates Pie'
$ou = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Disabled,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter *
foreach ($user in $ou) {
    $UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
        if ($_.name -notin $GroupsToKeep) {
            remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False
        } 
    }
}
```

That would remove each user in that OU from any group except 'Domain Users', 'O365 Licensing', and 'Hates Pie' (hating pie seems unnatural to me, gotta keep track of them, they might be vampires).

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a try. Thank you!